# returning an array from a function in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I am unable to return an array from a function call in Swift.

The script is a little bit longer now and little complicated as well, but this is basically what the output from within the function would look like:

```
func getRecentUpdates()
    {
        var updates = [("test", "hello"),("nice", "one")]

        println(updates) 

       return updates  
    }
```

println displays the array in the console but with the `return`, an error says `NSArray() is not convertible to ()`

Comment: hi user .. you do this thing .. `->` to indicate the return value of a function!

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
func getRecentUpdates()->[(String,String)]
{
    let updates = [("test", "hello"),("nice", "one")]

   return updates  
}
```

Comment: @Mika: You're right, I just felt like copying what they had and modifying it slightly so it would work. I will tweak my answer

Answer (score 0):

specter's update for swift 4:

```
func getRecentUpdates()-> Array<[String]>{
    let updates = [("test", "hello"),("nice", "one")]
    return updates  
}
```