# Returning Array from Function (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

This is my first question so please, be gentle!

I've been debugging my code and searching stackexchange.com for a while, and as best as I can tell, my problem has to do with return an array from a function. I can assure you that this is not a homework question, and I've tried going through Stackoverflow for solutions, and I'm at my wits end!

The `ActiveModelResponseList` is used to display a list of acceptable responses to the user, arranged in a `List` form:

```
struct ActiveModelResponseList: View {  
    var activeModel: ActiveModel  
    var body: some View {  
        List(activeModel.validResponses()) {  /* XCode error: "Cannot convert value of type  
                                                             '[ValidResponse]' to expected  
                                                             argument type 'Range<Int>'" */  
  
            HStack {  /* XCode error: "Contextual closure type '() -> TupleView<(Text, Text, Spacer)>'
                                      expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body" */  
                Text($0.response)  
                Text($0.narrative)  
                Spacer()  
            }.padding(10)  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I have tried a number of different ways to restructure the above `body`, and it's specifically that `activeModel.validResponses()` that causes the errors. If I delete it and populate the list with hard coded values, it works just fine.

That function, `activeModel.validResponses()` comes from the `ActiveModel` class, as follows:

```
class ActiveModel {
    var baseModel: ModelData
    private var responses: [Int]
    private var activeElement: Int
    
    // Although forThisElement is unused in the base function, ActiveModel still has  
    // such an element, used for other purposes  
  
    public func validResponses() -> [ValidResponse] {
        return (baseModel.validResponses(forThisElement: activeElement))
    }  
}
```

This, in turn, comes from a base class, `ModelData`. Note that `forThisElement` is not actually required for this function, but is included to maintain polymorphism (i.e. other models will use it). As you can see, `ModelData.validResponses` returns a `[ValidResponse]`

```
class ModelData: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {  
    var id: Int  
    var valid_response: [String]  
    var valid_response_narrative: [String]  
  
    public func validResponses(forThisElement: Int) -> [ValidResponse] {  
        // forThisElement is currently an unused input variable,  
        // but is required for compatibility with other classes

        var thisResult: [ValidResponse] = []  

        for thisResponse in 0..<valid_response.count {  
            thisResult[thisResponse].id = thisResponse  
            thisResult[thisResponse].response = valid_response[thisResponse]  
            thisResult[thisResponse].narrative = valid_response_narrative[thisResponse]  
        }  
        return thisResult  
    }  
}
```

The `ValidResponse` is just an ordinary struct, defined as follows:

```
struct ValidResponse: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int = 0  
    var response: String = "0"  
    var narrative: String = "Default"  
}
```

The preview is being generated for an iPod touch (7th generation), I'm using Xcode Version 13.1 (13A1030d), and am compiling using MacOS 12.0.1, on a mid-2015 MacBook Pro.

I found the following answers on stackexchange, but I feel none the wiser after having read them (and, as these answers are quite dated, I wonder if they're still relevant):

- [returning an array from a function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805921/returning-an-array-from-a-function-in-swift)
- [Return Array from Function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691433/return-array-from-function-in-swift)
- [Square every element in an Int of arrays. (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938499/square-every-element-in-an-int-of-arrays-swift)

Can anyone provide any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The first error message is nonsense. Fix the second and it will disappear.

The title of your question is unrelated to your actual problem, which is that you're trying to use a positional parameter from an outer closure. That doesn't work; they can't propagate that way. Every new closure scope gets its own set of positional parameters, and `HStack.init` doesn't use any, as the error tells you.

Fix: name the argument.

```swift
List(activeModel.validResponses()) { response in
  HStack {
    Text(response.response)
    Text(response.narrative)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've incorporated your change, but the preview doesn't generate; I get the error "Cannot preview in this file - Message send failure for send previewinstances message to agent".

I've tried restarting Xcode to clear this error (sometimes that seems to help) but to no avail